# debhelper deprecated option --until?

Tags: debian, packaging, buildbot

When building packages on a buildbot, I currently have a single buildstep which does

```
dpkg-buildpackage ...
```

This works great, but all the output is lumped together into a single step in the waterfall, which makes it hard to see at a glance whether the failure was during configure, during build, or during packaging.  So I'd like a finer grained way of building things.

It so happens that I know all the packages I want to build using dh.  That means I could have configure, build, test, and package buildsteps, each of which ran one of the following commands:

```
dh build --until dh_auto_configure
dh build --until dh_auto_build
dh build --until dh_auto_test
dpkg-buildpackage -nc ...
```

(I use dh to invoke these so it can do the overrides if the package uses any.  I don't want buildbot to have to know whether the package in question uses overrides.)

So far, so good.  The problem is, dh doesn't want me to use the --until option.  It says

"dh: The --until option is deprecated. Use override targets instead."

This makes me sad... sounds like dh doesn't anticipate this use case.

So, now the questions:

Where should such things be discussed?

Does dh actually handle my use case some other way, and I just missed the memo?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't a great job for `dh`. It really is just meant to be used from the `debian/rules` makefile, generally. The `--until` approach would likely have been pretty problematic for you, even if it wasn't deprecated.

You *could*, however, split up your build process by taking all the steps that `dpkg-buildpackage` takes in your own script (the summary at the top of the manpage should tell you everything you need).

But even that won't necessarily let you split up the `configure` and `build` parts of the process. `debian/rules` files are not [required](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules) to separate those steps or make it simple for the user to do so. Many do, some don't.

My recommendation would be to let `dpkg-buildpackage` do as much as possible in each phase, still, to avoid messing up something subtle with the build environment, dependency checking, tree prep, fakeroot invocation, or something. Just pass `-nc` on phases after the first to avoid cleaning up the tree and starting over. `dh` is smart enough, when phases overlap (like `build*` and `binary*`), to skip the parts you've already done.

You could get the right configure/build separation for most packages with something like:

```
set -e
# check build deps, clean tree, make source debs
dpkg-buildpackage -S -us -uc

if grep '^configure:' debian/rules; then
    debian/rules configure
elif grep '^override_dh_auto_configure:' debian/rules; then
    debian/rules override_dh_auto_configure
elif grep '^%:' debian/rules; then
    dh_auto_configure
else
    : # oh well, it'll get done during the build phase if necessary
fi

# prepare environment, perform build
dpkg-buildpackage -nc -T build

# install stuff into temp dir, tar it up, make the deb file
dpkg-buildpackage -nc -b -us -uc

# remake the changes file, if you care, since right now it only
# includes the binaries
dpkg-genchanges > ../$whatever.changes
```

At the very least, that should always make correct packages.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have control over all the packages in question, and have been converting them to dh.

Comment: (curse stackoverflow's UI :-)  For what it's worth, I have control over all the packages in question, and have been converting them to dh.  Also, since I'm using this to do things like run Coverity, if I use dpkg-buildpackage, I'll have to pass through one or more environment variables.  But I agree that using dpkg-buildpackage (or, better, debuild) is the Way To Build, and anything I hack together has to do what they do.